# jquery - Group element by Three

Tags: jquery, css

I have 12 `LI` elements. How to group them by three and check which `LI` has more height among three and assign greater height value to other two `LI` in the group.

The LIs will be dynamically populated and the height will differ to each other, so I like to keep 3 LIs in the row and check which has more height and apply it to other two LIs in the same row.

```
<ul>
  <li>001</li>
  <li>002</li>
  <li>003</li>
  <li>004</li>
  <li>005</li>
  <li>006</li>
  <li>007</li>
  <li>008</li>
  <li>009</li>
  <li>010</li>
  <li>011</li>
  <li>012</li>
 </ul>
```

Style as follows:

```
UL>LI{
float:Left;
width:33.33%
}
```

Comment: the question is unclear to me

Comment: Just do it in each function
$('ul > li').each(function(key,value){});  inside check if has next and compare sizes.

Comment: @Rickdep the LIs will be dynamically populated and the height will differ to each other, so I like to keep 3 LIs in the row and check which has more height and apply to rest of the two LIs in the same row. Hope that's clear now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A try from my side:

JS/Jquery

```
var list=$('ul>li');
for(var i=0;i<list.length;i+=3)
{
    max=-1;
    for(var j=i;j<i+3;j++)
    {
       var h = list[j].clientHeight; 
       max = h > max ? h : max;
    }
    for(var k=i;k<i+3;k++)
    {
        list[k].style.height = max+'px';
    }

}
```

You can use **offsetHeight** property also. It is similar to the clientHeight property, but it returns the height including the padding, scrollBar and the border.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Y6b9a/

Comment: If row have less then three LI element then your code will not work, is there any fix for it ?

Comment: @Syed Yes can replace i+3 and k+3 by number of rows. So you can define a variable noOfRows and can do i+noOfRows and k+noOfRows

Comment: Number of Rows is unknown, it will be generated dynamically. It could be one LI or could be Five LI and your works only if you have 3LI or 6LI or 9LI (grouped by three)